# SQL Django merge tables and update the foreign keys

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have 2 database A and B, both have table auth_user (id, username).
I have to merge them in the table auth_user in database B, check the new users and update the existing.
The problem now when I merge the users, the user Id will change, and I have to update all tables that point to the user with the new Id.

Any one have an idea how we can map the old user Id with the new user Id .

I am using Python, Django, MySQl.

Thanks for all help.